# Disable Apache cxf interceptor

Tags: java, apache, cxf, interceptor

I am developing a simulator to simulate client side web service. I have written the server side code. When I am trying to hit the service, I get the following exception on server side:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
```

As I am only developing a simulator, I do not need to validate the request (and its tags). I just want to send the response no matter whatever the request contains. Any idea how to suppress this error or disable these interceptors?

Comment: Dont do that. Validating messages i crucial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at the [Provider API](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/provider-services.html) which CXF provide.
In this case, CXF doesn't unmarshal the request message.